# Is there a way to return a response every x seconds or so to a single http request?

Tags: http

I'm wondering if it's possible to send a response every second or so to a single http request. Like for example the client makes an http request, then the server sends a space character every second. This could be never ending or with a limit, for example a minute.

I think the word 'response' is misleading in this context, since I don't necessarily mean an http response. The whole http response could be composed of the space characters, which would mean a single http response to a single http request, except that it is a minute long.

I tried chunked encoding but I don't think it works, or at least my implementation's wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets) to accomplish server-side pushing to the client. They allow you to open a connection to a server and receive responses from the server without issuing further requests from the client.

The [websocketstest](http://websocketstest.com/) page shows a WebSocket connection working in your browser (if it supports WebSockets), with an update of the server time pushed to the client every second.

The [socket.io](http://socket.io/) JavaScript library is a popular way to implement a WebSocket on the client side, with fallbacks for older browsers and support for [multiple sockets](http://socket.io/#announcement).

You'll also need to create a websocket server to listen for connections and serve responses. There are libraries for PHP, [Java](http://jwebsocket.org/), [Ruby](http://github.com/gimite/web-socket-ruby), [node.js](http://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node), [Python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-websocket), and others. There's a [tutorial here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/) that talks you through the client and server -side setup.

Note that not all browsers support WebSockets by default, although the socket.io library attempts to workaround this [[details](http://socket.io/#browser-support)].

Comment: Thanks. I'll read through that and see if it's applicable.